# iTunes Connect and Application Loader "You Must Define An Input Directory"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, application-loader

We're updating an existing application that was created using Adobe Creative Cloud, and currently being uploaded via Application Loader.

Prior apps developed with the same toolset that were updated never showed this issue (although there were other issues that we solved). And we haven't really seen this particular issue, which suggest that it might be SOMEWHERE in the application itself, but since it was largely generated and outputted in the same way as the prior version of the app, we're not sure where to look.

The error shown when ADDING APPLICATION is "You must define an input directory."

This seems pretty fundamental, but we can't find it anywhere in the app. Help!

Comment: I also started getting this today after only minor updates to my app, which is built via Adobe PhoneGap Build.

Comment: Same error with me while updating app from Appliation Loader. Please share solution if anyone have.

Comment: Same error with Application Loader 2.5.1 :( Which version is yours?

Comment: wanting252 -- it was resolved via upgrading Application Loader (thanks to Viken, by the way). I had Application Loader 2.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your Application Loader version to 3.0 and It will work.

Comment: Worked for me. I had the problem on version 2.8 and version 3.0 is working fine.

Comment: Thanks!

Sorry, I didn't respond right away -- this worked for me (and apparently for a number of other people with similar problems).

Upgrading to the latest version (of course, requiring that the OS be of a certain minimum version, etc., etc.) resolved the issue entirely.

Comment: I'm having the problem in version 2.7. Do I need to update the whole Xcode? or just Application Loader can be updated?